# Disable keyboard input for QFontComboBox

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, qcombobox

Is it possible to disable keyboard input for a QFontComboBox? The following code:

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class FontComboBox(QFontComboBox):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FontComboBox, self).__init__(parent)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    fonts = FontComboBox()
    fonts.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

gives me (Mac OS X 10.8, PyQt4.8) a combobox which is *editable* and lets the user input basically anything. QtCreator, on the other hand, has this nice solution:

[image: qtcreator font-selector]

which looks more like an ordinary QComboBox. I've searched far and wide but can't seem to find settings for disabling keyboard input/changing the look of QFontComboBox. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [QFontComboBox](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfontcombobox.html) *is* a [QComboBox](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html) (i.e. a subclass of it), so all you need to do is:

```
    fonts.setEditable(False)
```

Comment: ekhumoro, thanks (again)! Turns out the actual problem was something else: This particular fontbox belonged to an item in a QTreeView. It was returned by .createEditor() of a subclass of QStyledItemDelegate. When setting isEditable() to False, editing of the QTreeView was completely disabled. After reading your answer, I knew where to look for the problem, wrapped the non-editable fontbox in a widget and let .createEditor() return that widget instead.